# Create a Java Point array that moves randomly toward a defined end point

Tags: java, arrays, random, point

I've issued myself a sort of challenge, and thought I could stand to ask for help getting my head around it. I want to use java Graphics to draw something that looks like lightning striking a given point.

Right now I just have this, which shoots cheap "lightning" in random directions, and I don't care where it ends up.

```
lightning[0] = new Point(370,130); //This is a given start point.

// Start in a random direction, each line segment has a length of 25
double theta = rand.nextDouble()*2*Math.PI;
int X = (int)(25*Math.cos(theta));
int Y = (int)(25*Math.sin(theta));

//Populate the array with more points
for (int i = 1 ; i < lightning.length ; i++)
{
  lightning[i] = new Point(X + lightning[i-1].x, Y + lightning[i-1].y);

  boolean plusminus = rand.nextBoolean();
  if (plusminus) theta = theta + rand.nextDouble()*(Math.PI/2);
  else theta = theta - rand.nextDouble()*(Math.PI/2);

  X = (int)(25*Math.cos(theta));
  Y = (int)(25*Math.sin(theta));
}

// Draw lines connecting each point
canvas.setColor(Color.WHITE);
for (int i = 1 ; i < lightning.length ; i++)
{
  int Xbegin = lightning[i-1].x;
  int Xend = lightning[i].x;
  int Ybegin = lightning[i-1].y;
  int Yend = lightning[i].y;

  canvas.drawLine(Xbegin, Ybegin, Xend, Yend);

  //if (Xend != Xbegin) theta = Math.atan((Yend - Ybegin)/(Xend - Xbegin));

  // Restrict the angle to 90 degrees in either direction
  boolean plusminus = rand.nextBoolean();
  if (plusminus) theta = theta + rand.nextDouble()*(Math.PI/2);
  else theta = theta - rand.nextDouble()*(Math.PI/2);

  // 50/50 chance of creating a half-length off-shoot branch on the end
  if (rand.nextBoolean())
  {
    int Xoff = (int)(Xend+(12*Math.cos(theta)));
    int Yoff = (int)(Yend+(12*Math.sin(theta)));

    canvas.drawLine(Xend, Yend, Xoff, Yoff);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to think of some similar way to create this effect, but have the last point in the array pre-defined, so that the lightning can "strike" a specific point. In other words, I want to populate a Point array in a way that is random, but still converges on one final point.

Anyone care to weigh in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is fairly simple, accurate, and elegant approach.  It uses a divide and conquer strategy.  Start with only 2 values:

- start point
- end point

Calculate the midpoint.  Offset that midpoint some value `variance` (which can be calculated relative to the length).  The offset should ideally be normal to the vector connecting start and end, but you could be cheap by making that offset horizontal, as long as your bolts travel mostly vertically, like real lightning.  Repeat above procedure for both (start, offset_mid) and (offset_mid, end), but this time using a smaller number for `variance`.  This is a recursive approach which can terminate when either a threshold variance is achieved, or a threshold line segment length.  As the recursion unwinds, you can draw all the connector segments.  The idea is that the largest variance happens in the center of the bolt (when the start-to-end distance is the longest), and with each recursive call, the distance between points shrinks, and so does the variance.  This way, the global variance of the bolt will be much greater than any local variances (like a real lightning bolt).

Here is an image of 3 different bolts generated from the same pre-determined points with this algorithm.  Those points happen to be (250,100) and (500,800).  If you want bolts that travel in any direction (not just "mostly vertical"), then you'll need to add more complexity to the point shifting code, shifting both X and Y based on the angle of travel of the bolt.

[image: lightning]

And here is some Java code for this approach.  I used an `ArrayList` since the the divide and conquer approach doesn't know ahead of time how many elements it will end up with.

```
// play with these values to fine-tune the appearance of your bolt
private static final double VAR_FACTOR = 0.40;
private static final double VAR_DECREASE = 0.55;
private static final int MIN_LENGTH = 50;

public static ArrayList<Point> buildBolt(Point start, Point end) {
    ArrayList<Point> bolt = new ArrayList<Point>();
    double dx = start.getX() - end.getX();
    double dy = start.getY() - end.getY();
    double length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    double variance = length * VAR_FACTOR;
    bolt.add(start);
    buildBolt(start, end, bolt, variance);
    return bolt;
}

private static void buildBolt(Point start, Point end,
                              List<Point> bolt, double variance) {
    double dx = start.getX() - end.getX();
    double dy = start.getY() - end.getY();
    double length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    if (length > MIN_LENGTH) {        
        int varX = (int) ((Math.random() * variance * 2) - variance);
        int midX = (start.x + end.x)/2 + varX;
        int midY = (start.y + end.y)/2;
        Point mid = new Point(midX, midY);
        buildBolt(start, mid, bolt, variance * VAR_DECREASE);
        buildBolt(mid, end, bolt, variance * VAR_DECREASE);
    } else {
        bolt.add(end);
    }
    return;      
}
```

Comment: ...Actually, I'm still a bit curious how you drew the lightning using an arraylist. My immediate instinct was to convert it to an array, which works, but... what did you do?

Comment: You can iterate through an ArrayList just like you'd iterate through an array.  That's the whole point of ArrayLists. :-)  Here are the 3 files I used to make the image above: http://pastebin.com/haxQ3yyq   http://pastebin.com/0h8PkLWn   http://pastebin.com/D6Ec2KnU

Answer (score 1):

Without any graphics experience, I have this advice: it's going to be hard to pick a specific point, then try to reach it in a "random" way. Instead, I'd recommend creating a straight line from the origin to destination, then randomly bending parts of it. You could make several passes, bending smaller and smaller segments down to a certain limit to get the desired look. Again, I'm saying this without any knowledge of the graphics API.